# pandas: HTML output with conditional formatting

Tags: python, html, css, dataframe, pandas

I am trying to format a table, such that data in each column are formatted in a style depending on their values (similar to conditional formatting in spreadsheet programs). How can I achieve that in pandas using the HTML formatter?

A typical use case is highlighting significant values in a table. For example:

```
    correlation  p-value
0   0.5          0.1
1   0.1          0.8
2   0.9          *0.01*
```

pandas allows to define custom formatters for HTML output - to obtain above output one could use:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core import format
from StringIO import StringIO
buf = StringIO()
df = pd.DataFrame({'correlation':[0.5, 0.1,0.9], 'p_value':[0.1,0.8,0.01]})
fmt = format.DataFrameFormatter(df, 
          formatters={'p_value':lambda x: "*%f*" % x if x<0.05 else str(x)})
format.HTMLFormatter(fmt).write_result(buf)
```

However, I would like to change the style for significant values (for example, by using bold font).

A possible solution would be to attach a CSS class to `<td>` tags in the HTML output, which could be then formatted using CSS stylesheet. The above would then become:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>correlation</th>
      <th>p_value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td> 0.5</td>
      <td> 0.10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td> 0.1</td>
      <td> 0.80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td> 0.9</td>
      <td class='significant'> 0.01</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Edit**: As suggested by @Andy-Hayden I can add formatting by simply replacing stars with `<span class="signifcant">...</span>` in my example:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
buf = StringIO()
significant = lambda x: '<span class="significant">%f</span>' % x if x<0.05 else str(x)
df = pd.DataFrame({'correlation':[0.5, 0.1,0.9], 'p_value':[0.1,0.8,0.01]})
df.to_html(buf, formatters={'p_value': significant})
```

Newer versions of pandas escape the tags. To avoid it replace last line with:

```
df.to_html(buf, formatters={'p_value': significant}, escape=False)
```

Comment: Can I use to_html with formatters to write the value of buf to an html file directly?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the DataFrame [`to_html`](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html?highlight=to_html#pandas.DataFrame.to_html) method, which comes with `formatters` argument.

*An easier solution would be to surround by `<span class="significant">` and `</span>`, (rather than `*`). Note: by default this will be escaped (i.e. `<` becomes `&lt;`) so you will need to use the `escape=False` argument.*

Comment: That is an excellent idea, thanks! I basically replace the stars in my example code above with `<span class...>`. The significance is decided based on values in `p-value` column.

Comment: This doesn't work as expected since the `span` tag is escaped : `<td>&lt;span class='significant'&gt; ...`

Comment: @PhE you have to pass in escape=False to make this work now. :)

Answer (score 8):

Since pandas 0.17.1, it is easy to apply custom formatting
to the data frame HTML representation using the
[styling api](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'correlation':[0.5, 0.1,0.9],
    'p_value':[0.1,0.8,0.01]})
styled_df = df.style.apply(
    lambda x: ['font-weight: bold; background-color: yellow'
               if value <= 0.01 else '' for value in x])
styled_df
```

[image]

The output is rendered automatically in interfaces such as the Jupyter Notebook
and the string representation of the HTML can be returned with the `render()`
method.

```
print(styled_df.render())
```

```
<style  type="text/css" >
    #T_4e49b9da_8451_11e8_9166_605718a99a7frow2_col1 {
            font-weight:  bold;
             background-color:  yellow;
            font-weight:  bold;
             background-color:  yellow;
        }</style>  
<table id="T_4e49b9da_8451_11e8_9166_605718a99a7f" > 
<thead>    <tr> 
        <th class="blank level0" ></th> 
        <th class="col_heading level0 col0" >correlation</th> 
        <th class="col_heading level0 col1" >p_value</th> 
    </tr></thead> 
<tbody>    <tr> 
        <th id="T_4e49b9da_8451_11e8_9166_605718a99a7flevel0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" >0</th> 
        <td id="T_4e49b9da_8451_11e8_9166_605718a99a7frow0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >0.5</td> 
        <td id="T_4e49b9da_8451_11e8_9166_605718a99a7frow0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >0.1</td> 
    </tr>    <tr> 
        <th id="T_4e49b9da_8451_11e8_9166_605718a99a7flevel0_row1" class="row_heading level0 row1" >1</th> 
        <td id="T_4e49b9da_8451_11e8_9166_605718a99a7frow1_col0" class="data row1 col0" >0.1</td> 
        <td id="T_4e49b9da_8451_11e8_9166_605718a99a7frow1_col1" class="data row1 col1" >0.8</td> 
    </tr>    <tr> 
        <th id="T_4e49b9da_8451_11e8_9166_605718a99a7flevel0_row2" class="row_heading level0 row2" >2</th> 
        <td id="T_4e49b9da_8451_11e8_9166_605718a99a7frow2_col0" class="data row2 col0" >0.9</td> 
        <td id="T_4e49b9da_8451_11e8_9166_605718a99a7frow2_col1" class="data row2 col1" >0.01</td> 
    </tr></tbody> 
</table>
```