# pandas.to_html() returning None

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use the formatters argument to add a html property to a specific cell/text. 
I've found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627380/pandas-html-output-with-conditional-formatting) that fits completely my request. However trying it, results in returning None. 
The example that I'm trying:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

buf = StringIO()
significant = lambda x: '<span class="significant">%f</span>' % x if x<0.05 else str(x)
df = pd.DataFrame({'correlation':[0.5, 0.1,0.9], 'p_value':[0.1,0.8,0.01]})
print df.to_html(buf, formatters={'p_value': significant}, escape=False)
```

This question is from 2013. Does the syntax changed from one version to another?
I'm using python Python 2.7.9 pandas 0.16.0.

Comment: Meybe result is in `buf`?

Comment: As above: the to_x methods return None, the results will be visible in whatever file-like you pass as the first parameter

Comment: Ok, I wasn't understanding the stringIo use. I was thinking the formatter argument required a stringIo object. The result that I was expecting was simply: df.to_html(formatters={'p_value': significant}, escape=False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given the [DataFrame.to_html](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) function a StringIO buffer, which means that the result is written to it, not returned as a string.

This has not changed since [Pandas version 0.10 of DataFrame.to_html() function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.10.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html)

To get the output as a returned string, simply remove the buffer:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'correlation':[0.5, 0.1,0.9],
     'p_value':[0.1,0.8,0.01]})
strformat = '<span class="significant">%f</span>'
significant = lambda x: strformat % x if x<0.05 else str(x)
formatters = {'p_value': significant}

print df.to_html(formatters=formatters, escape=False)
```

OR, if you want to use a buffer, this is how to print the value of it:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'correlation':[0.5, 0.1,0.9],
     'p_value':[0.1,0.8,0.01]})
strformat = '<span class="significant">%f</span>'
significant = lambda x: strformat % x if x<0.05 else str(x)
formatters = {'p_value': significant}

buf = StringIO()
df.to_html(buf, formatters=formatters, escape=False)
print buf.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 1):

The df.to_html() method is not returning the output, the output is returned to the buf stringIo object wich can be conveniently written later.
What I was expecting:

```
   import pandas as pd
   significant = lambda x: '<span class="significant">%f</span>' % x if x<0.05 else str(x)
   df = pd.DataFrame({'correlation':[0.5, 0.1,0.9], 'p_value':[0.1,0.8,0.01]})
   print df.to_html(formatters={'p_value': significant}, escape=False)
```