# Pandas HTML Output Conditional Formatting - Highlight cell if value in range

Tags: html, pandas, formatting, conditional-statements

I am building report in HTML format using pd.to_html() method. Can anyone clarify how can i format cells with values between -0.5 and 0.5 with green back ground for particular columns of data frame?

Comment: What have you tried so far, have you got any samples of the code not working we can help you with?

Comment: Unfortunately even cant find any example to try

Comment: Have you had a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627380/pandas-html-output-with-conditional-formatting?rq=1)? it might be some help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do custom formatting of DataFrames using the `style` attribute (introduced starting from pandas v0.17.1). 
An example to do what you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5), columns=list('ABCDE'))

def highlight_vals(val, min=-0.5, max=0.5, color='green'):
    if min < val < max:
        return 'background-color: %s' % color
    else:
        return ''

df.style.applymap(highlight_vals, subset=['B', 'C', 'D'])
```

gives you

[image]

See this notebook for the full example: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/jorisvandenbossche/8b74f71734cd6d75a58c5a048261a7a7

And see the docs for more example how to format the dataframe: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html

To write the output to a file, you can do:

```
with open('filename.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df.style.applymap(highlight_vals, subset=['B', 'C', 'D'])
                    .set_table_attributes("border=1").render())
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i looked. Will try

Comment: How can i add the path for HTML output? Want to print file in specific location. None of the examples doesn't show that. Thank you

Comment: @Felix you will have to write the string that `render` returns to a file yourself. I added an example how to do this.

Comment: Thank you, @joris. For some reason in saved html page coloring working fine but borders from table disappeared. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: You're correct. For some reason, the style template does not include `border=1` in the table tag. You can add this with `.set_table_attributes("border=1")`. I updated the answer.

Comment: works perfect, thank you. Any place in documentation to find this? Appreciate your help.