# How to change background cell color according with a given key in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"],  
                   "B":["A","A","B","A"], 
                   "C":[0,3,1,1]})
```

How can I change the cell color of columns A and B, grouped by its values. I mean, this would be the desirable output:

[image]

Maybe something like:

```
df.groupby(by=['A', 'B']).style.change_background()
```

As the real dataframe has hundreds of rows, I'd be interestested in assigning the colors automatically.

Comment: May be : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638402/pandas-html-output-conditional-formatting-highlight-cell-if-value-in-range

Comment: Thanks! But using this approach you can't just groupby by two columns and asign each group a different color automatically.

Comment: What do you mean by according to key? Do you mean for a value of C you will set a color?

Comment: No, by the composed value of A and B. I've updated the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm 
from matplotlib.colors import to_hex

# convert groups to indices    
g = pd.Categorical(df.A + df.B).codes

# generate a list hex colors
color = cm.rainbow(g / g.max())
hex_color = [to_hex(col) for col in color]
print('generate colors: ', hex_color)

# apply the colors to style for columns A and B
df.style.apply(
    lambda col: ['background-color: %s' % (hex_color[i]) for i in range(col.size)], 
    subset=['A', 'B']
)
```

[image]

**Update by Antonvbr:** (Insipred by this solution I added a solution using [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html) too).

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"],  
                   "B":["A","A","B","A"], 
                   "C":[0,3,1,1]})

g = pd.Categorical(df.A + df.B).codes # convert groups to indices  
n = np.unique(g).size
palette = sns.color_palette("hls", n).as_hex()

# apply the colors to style for columns A and B
df.style.apply(
    lambda x: ['background-color: {}'.format(palette[i]) for i in g], 
    subset=['A', 'B']
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! And what if I've already set one style previously? I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'style'`. In oder words, how do apply two different styles to a dataframe? Cheers!

Comment: @harrison4 Exemplify what you mean with code. But this looks more like a new question. [at]Psidom I modified your answer to include the popular Seaborn package, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @AntonvBR Not a problem. Good edit to include the `seaborn` option here.

Comment: @harrison4 I guess you are using `style` on your previous style. just use `apply` to chain the styles. i.e. `df.style.apply(...style1).apply(...style2)` instead of `df.style.apply(...).style.apply(...)`.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much, Psidom! :)