# xlsxwriter data_label background color

Tags: pandas, plot, bar-chart, xlsxwriter

[image]I am trying to create a column plot where each column has a different color. Plus I need to add ".data_labels" - so the values are visible.

Currently, I can change color of the font (in the data_labels). But I can't find how I can add "background color" to that label.

I want to make sure that black text will be on white background on top of the column (columns will have light and dark colors - so, it is not enough to change color of the font).

So, this will look like there is a white text box on top of column. Inside the box ("data_label") is text in black.

Note: I am using stacked graph, so I can't put text outside column (e.g. on top of the bar).

```
chart.add_series({ (...),
                  'data_labels': {'value' : True, 'position': 'inside_base',
                                  'font': {'color': 'black', 'bg_color': 'white'}})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change background cell color according with a given key in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590369/how-to-change-background-cell-color-according-with-a-given-key-in-pandas)

Comment: It is not changing color of the cell. I want to add label to a chart (white background - black text). BTW: I have checked if 'bg_color' or 'fill' will work - they didn't. Documentation doesn't seem to have this option defined.

Comment: can you add an image of what you want to see?

Comment: @Yuca - here is the image. This is a label - marked with the arrow. So, data_labels - should have option to have a background color.

Comment: Data label fill colors or associated properties aren't currently supported in XlsxWriter. You should open a feature request for it on GitHub.