# How to change to background color

Tags: python, html, css, pandas, styles

How would I change the background color instead of font color ?

```
def cloud_height_style_function(vals): 
    return pd.cut(vals,[-np.inf,199,499,999,3000, np.inf], # need to review the bin a bit
              labels=[f'color: {c}' for c in ['#9400D3','#FFA500','#FF0000','#FFFF00','#00b050']])
```

If I change the labels to

```
    labels=['background-color: %s' for c in ['#9400D3','#FFA500','#FF0000','#FFFF00','#00b050']])
```

it gives me 
      ValueError: ('Categorical categories must be unique', 'occurred at index cld_hgt'

Here is the dataframe I would to use

```
    icao msg_type              time    dt  ddd  ff    gg flt_cat   vis  cld_hgt cld_type present_wx vis_obc
0   KLAX  ROUTINE  2019-10-14 00:53  1:00  260  10 -9999     VFR  10.0     9999     9999       None   -9999
1   KLAX  ROUTINE  2019-10-14 01:53  1:00  240   9 -9999     VFR  10.0     9999     9999       None   -9999
2   KLAX  ROUTINE  2019-10-14 02:53  1:00  260   6 -9999     VFR  10.0     9999     9999       None   -9999
3   KLAX  ROUTINE  2019-10-14 03:53  1:00  250   5 -9999     VFR  10.0     9999     9999       None   -9999
4   KLAX  ROUTINE  2019-10-14 04:53  1:00  240   4 -9999     VFR  10.0     9999     9999       None   -9999
5   KLAX  ROUTINE  2019-10-14 05:53  1:00  250   5 -9999     VFR  10.0     9999     9999       None   -9999
```

This is a continuation of of [Apply Multiple Styles to a data frame specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442947/apply-multiple-styles-to-a-data-frame-specific-column/58443364#58443364)

Comment: working fine for me, no error, are you using this dataframe?

Comment: yes I am. I am working with that specific dataframe using def cloud_height_style_function(vals): 
    return pd.cut(vals,[-np.inf,199,499,999,3000, np.inf], # need to review the bin a bit
              labels=['background-color: %s' for c in ['#9400D3','#FFA500','#FF0000','#FFFF00','#00b050']])

Answer (score 0):

def cloud_height_style_function(vals): 
    return pd.cut(vals,[-np.inf,199,499,999,3000, np.inf], labels=[f'backngroud-color: {c}' for c in ['#9400D3','#FFA500','#FF0000','#FFFF00','#00b050']])