# How to apply background-color to pandas dataframe based on specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I've been trying to add background-color to a dataframe based on a condition (if the element matches the values present in a list). I found a way to change the color of the text based on the condition, but couldn't find a way to change the background-color instead.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
#lists
removed_list = ['Blah Blah', 'BlahBlah2', 'BlahBlah3']
added_list = ['Service Fee']

#method to color-code based on condition
def color_negative_red(value):

  if value in removed_list:
    color = 'red'
  elif value in added_list:
    color = 'blue'
  else:
    color = ''

  return 'color: %s' % color

final_df = df.style.applymap(color_negative_red)
```

Now, when I'm printing final_df, I get:

[image: The column names from "removed_list" are coded RED and columns from "added_list" are coded BLUE, while all other columns are default]

All I want to do is, instead of changing the color of the text, I want to add background color to the above highlighted values in the dataframe.

Please help!

Comment: Hi PKV, make sure you do a good search in further posting, I assume unfortunately that this thread is a duplicate, please check this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590369/how-to-change-background-cell-color-according-with-a-given-key-in-pandas], the pandas documentation itself is also very good and explains how to use it [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html]

Comment: Try... `return 'background-color: %s' % color`  or using f-string in Python 3.6+ `return f'background-color: {color}'`